# How to open oft files in Linux

Tags: compatibility, file-format

I have some older (around 2010) .oft files (seem to be mails stored in an MS Outlook format) which I need to open (or convert and open) in Kubuntu 17.04.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The [OFT](https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/oft) file extension is known as `Outlook File Template` which was developed by Microsoft. It is a file format used for e-mail template and contains a pre-formatted layout which is used for creating custom messages with a similar look and feel to help save time. More specifically it contains company email and personal information management application. as @Rinzwind said you can open an `OFT` file only using `Microsoft Office Outlook` or `Microsoft Outlook Express`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no other software than Outlook to open .oft.

> seem to be mails stored in an MS Outlook format

No, ".oft" is an template for formatting mails in outlook. Not actual mails.
Mails (and other personal data like contacts) should be a ".pst" (Personal Storage Table).

---

Here is an example of an OFT (using VB.net):

```
' Load the Outlook template (OFT) file in MailMessage's instance
Dim message As MailMessage = MailMessage.Load("invitation to meeting.oft", MessageFormat.Msg)  

' Set the sender and recipients information  
Dim senderDisplayName As String = "John"    
Dim senderEmailAddress As String = "john@abc.com"    
Dim recipientDisplayName As String = "William"    
Dim recipientEmailAddress As String = "william@xzy.com"    
message.Sender = New MailAddress(senderEmailAddress, senderDisplayName)    
message.To.Add(New MailAddress(recipientEmailAddress, recipientDisplayName))    
message.HtmlBody = message.HtmlBody.Replace("DisplayName", "" & recipientDisplayName & "")

' Set the name, location and time in email body    
Dim meetingLocation As String = "" & "Hall 1, Convention Center, New York, USA" & ""    
Dim meetingTime As String = "" & "Monday, June 28, 2010" & ""    
message.HtmlBody = message.HtmlBody.Replace("MeetingPlace", meetingLocation)    
message.HtmlBody = message.HtmlBody.Replace("MeetingTime", meetingTime)

' Send the email or save as MSG and open in Outlook for further editing    
Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("host", 25, "username", "password")    
client.Send(message)

' Save the message in MSG format and open in Office Outlook    
Dim msg As MapiMessage = MapiMessage.FromMailMessage(message)    
msg.SetMessageFlags(MapiMessageFlags.MSGFLAG_UNSENT)    
msg.Save("Invitation.msg")    
Process.Start("Invitation.msg")
```

Comment: The files in question are about 4MB to 8MB (rather waistful for storing only formatting) and are named like mails. Are you sure they are only formatting and I won't find the actual mail in there?

Comment: If there is an image inside the template or something dynamic (like dates, names, addresses) 4Mb is nothing. I added an example OFT; lots of things going on but the actual message is not in it.

Comment: finally installed Outlook 2000 via wine. The files did include the mail message itself and attachments etc...